# how to fix "image defined in density-independent folder" error?

Tags: android, android-studio, error-handling

I copy pasted over a 600+ images in android studio to use as an imagebutton as it seemed to work perfectly fine when I first tried it out, but when I tried to run the application once I was done with all the code, I got this error. How can I solve this?

[image]

We tried to suppress all of the errors but I'm afraid that it will do it again as I need to import over a thousand images to use as an imagebutton...

Comment: We can't help you without you providing some proper error. Don't post images of text, errors are text. Please follow this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question.

Comment: And why would you import 600+ images for a single image button ? What's the purpose ?

Comment: @ItzDavi it's not a single image button, I need to make over 600+ imagebutton that's why

Comment: @ItzDavi i got it fixed now, but my new problem is that i get a red line when i update my targetsdk to 34..

Comment: Can you add your new error stack trace updating your question ?